# Spring boot MVC - logging all responses with correct status including 500

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

There are several examples (such as http://www.javabyexamples.com/request-logging-using-spring-mvc) on how to log all requests/responses from a MVC spring boot application.

They are working well as long as no 500 response is generated by spring boot. In such case, the response status logged is 200 whereas the real response received by the client is 500...

Why is this happening and how to fix this flaw to log 500 instead of 200?

Thanks.